# How to disable or shorten the tooltip delay in QTableView?

Tags: qt, qt5

We are using a `QTableView` with a custom `QAbstractTableModel`. Some data is too long to display in the cells directly or we would like to show additional information.

In the model we use the following code:

```
QVariant MyTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return "Short Content";
    }

    if (role == Qt::ToolTipRole) {
        return "Super long content which contains line\nbreaks, tabs\t and more.";
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

This works and when hovering the cells the tooltip is displayed. **However,** this takes a few seconds for the tooltip to appear and sometimes some mouse-wiggling.

Is there a built-in way in Qt 5 to disable the timeout and always display the tooltip?

Comment: see https://forum.qt.io/topic/90403/show-tooltip-immediatly/6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As they point out in the [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/90403/show-tooltip-immediatly/6) the delay depends on the style and is returned through [`SH_ToolTip_WakeUpDelay`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StyleHint-enum) which is [700 ms by default](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/58c69df4d38324644bc49ec5f42ee8343a454b2d/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp#L5362).

Considering the above, a possible solution is to use the QProxyStyle method override:

```
class ProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;
    int styleHint(StyleHint hint, const QStyleOption* option = nullptr, const QWidget* widget = nullptr, QStyleHintReturn* returnData = nullptr) const override
    {
        if (hint == QStyle::SH_ToolTip_WakeUpDelay)
            return 0;
        return QProxyStyle::styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData);
    }
};
```

```
tableview->setStyle(new ProxyStyle(tableview->style()));
```

Comment: can you please post another example in Python?